Any better ways to find the range of the inclination angle for the moving line PM?
Problem:
Given two points A(-3,4) and B(3,2), for a straight line l passing through point P(1,0) that intersects with segment AB, what is the range of the inclination angle α? And what is the range of the slope k?


Clear["`*"]
a = {-3, 4}; b = {3, 2}; p = {1, 0};
m[t_] := a + t (b - a)
FunctionRange[{(p[[2]] - m[t][[2]])/(p[[1]] - m[t][[1]]), 
  0 <= t <= 1}, t, k]
Reduce[{FunctionRange[{(p[[2]] - m[t][[2]])/(p[[1]] - m[t][[1]]), 
    0 <= t <= 1}, t, k], Tan@\[Theta] == k, 
  0 <= \[Theta] <= \[Pi]}, \[Theta], {k}]


I used the method above to determine the slope range of the moving line PM, but I'm missing a π/2 in the range of the inclination angle. Is there a good way to find the range of the inclination angle for the moving line PM?

Since the slope, $k$, is undefined for the vertical line, one trick is to use reciprocal slope instead of $k$ to obtain a continuous range.  The following code, basically, exchanges your subscripts 1&2 and replaces tangent with cotangent.
Clear["Global`*"]
a = {-3, 4}; b = {3, 2}; p = {1, 0};
m[t_] := a + t (b - a)

r = FunctionRange[{Divide@@(p - m[t]),0 <= t <= 1}, t, {kinv}];

krange = r /. kinv -> 1/k

Reduce[{r, Cot[\[Alpha]] == kinv, 0 <= \[Alpha] <= \[Pi]}, \[Alpha], {kinv}]

$-1\leq\frac{1}{k}\leq1$
$\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\alpha\leq\frac{3\pi}{4}$
My personal preference is to write the range of $k$ as $k^2 \ge 1$.

Converting the range of line inclinations to a range of vector angles.
Clear["`*"]
a = {-3, 4}; b = {3, 2}; p = {1, 0};
m[t_] := a + t (b - a)
FunctionRange[{VectorAngle[m[t] - p, {1, 0}], 0 <= t <= 1}, t, y]


(*\[Pi]/4\[LessEqual]y\[LessEqual](3 \[Pi])/4*)
```

